# MySQL - Get time in minutes for time values over an hour

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have time stored in my table in the following format

```
*----------*-----------*
|   press  |    time   |
*----------*-----------*
|Press One | 00:45:23  |
|Press Two | 01:01:34  |
```

Where time is in %hh %mm %ss format. What I need is the average of the time column grouped by press column where time returned is in minutes. With the following query I get what I need until the time average is 59 minutes. And I understand that TIME_FORMAT(x, '%i') will give 0-59 minutes.

My Question: How do I get the time average to return in Minutes even if returned time is over 59 minutes.

```
SELECT press, 
       TIME_FORMAT(
           SEC_TO_TIME(
               TRUNCATE(
                   AVG(time)
               , 0)
           )
       ,'%i') 
      as time 
FROM pressmr 
GROUP BY press
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did not find a MySql function for this but just ended up using basic math. Here my new query

```
SELECT press, 
           TRUNCATE(
               AVG(time)/60
           , 0)
  as time 
FROM pressmr 
GROUP BY press
```

I just ended up getting the average time which returned total seconds and divided by 60 to get it in minutes.